# If a cell has a value move adjacent cell to that location

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have some data that looks like this:

```
Upstream    6.36
Downstream  6.25
Downstream  6.36
Upstream    6.25
```

What I want is, if the cell says `Upstream`, replace the word `Upstream` with the value in the cell next to it e.g.`6.36`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming first `Upstream` is in A1 and first `6.36` in B1, a simple formula might be sufficient. Insert a column between the two existing and in B1:

```
=IF(A1="Upstream",C1,A1)
```

copied down to suit. Select ColumnB, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top and delete ColumnA.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some code like the following to do what you want:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 4
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = "Upstream" Then
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 2)
    End If
Next i
```